# Установлен wordpress но, как теперь сделать главную страницу?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cms

Установил wp но есть необходимость изменить главную страницу с index.php на main.php и я воспользовался директивой htaccess **DirectoryIndex main.php** всё заработало Но так же в меню есть ссылка на это блог wordpress и при клике возвращается опять на main.php ,но не меняя подкаталоги и каталоги как это решить ?помогите

Comment: а если в настройках темы выбрать Статическую страницу указав страницу main

Comment: так должно сработать ?

Comment: Если мне нужно в качестве главной страницы использовать определенную страницу то я так и делаю. Создаю страницу и настройках темы в разделе "Статическая главная страница" указываю ее.

Comment: там нету этого пункта ? нету что бы выбрать какую именно страницу , один пункт всего Пример страницы

Comment: "Пример страницы" это страница штатная (для примера) в wp, вам же нужно создать свою и указать ее в этом списке. После создания она там будет присутствовать.

Comment: ааа , я понял , я имел ввиду как указать вообще другую страницу ? не из списка wordpress

Comment: Если вы создаете нестатическую страницу (то есть не в админке через Страницы -> Добавить новую), то она и не появится в списке. Вариант с фильтром `template_include` подойдет?

Comment: подробнее можно ?

Comment: а какова цель отображения страницы не из wp?

Comment: заказчик - как всегда Он такое хочет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с переопределением шаблона. Используется фильтр `template_include`.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1 );

function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
   if(is_home() || is_front_page()){
        if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'main.php' ) ) ) 
            $template_path = $theme_file;
        // или какое-то другое условие и присваивание
   }
   return $template_path;
}
```

Comment: это в wp-config.php вставлять ?

Comment: В основной файл плагина или в functions.php темы - смотря что вы можете редактировать. Если тема сторонняя, то создайте дочернюю от нее, чтобы ваши изменения не потерялись при обновлении родительской темы.

Comment: в общем самое просто оказалось создать второй сайт , точнее примерно так allweb.ru в котором была ссылка на blog.allweb.ru